# nodemailer: Connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I deployed a function to firebase and when I test the function to send an email I get the following error:

```
Error: Connection closed unexpectedly
    at SMTPConnection._onClose (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:824:34)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketClose (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:191:42)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:537:15)
    at net.js:686:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:564:7)
    at TCP.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)
```

This is the function I use to send the email:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "host",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: "email",
    pass: "pass",
  },
});

exports.sendMailUser =
  functions.firestore.document("collection/Users").onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.after.data();
    const dataReceived = data.users;
    const name = dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].name;
    const email = dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].email;
    const password = dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].password;
    const body = "As dori crearea unui cont pe portalul e-Radauti cu urmatoarele date: <br>" + name + "<br>" + email + "<br>" + "password" + password;
    const mailOptions = {
      from: "Adaugare User pe portal-ul e-Radauti",
      to: "mail",
      subject: "Adaugare user pe portalul e-Radauti",
      bcc: "bcc",
      html: body,
    };
    console.log(mailOptions);
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return null;
  });
```

Edit:
I've updated the code with @Dharmaraj suggestion and also I have the Blaze(Pay as you go) plan

[image]

Comment: Can you try making the function async and then `await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);`? Then just `return null` at end?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've tried but it's not working

Comment: Did you take a look to the function logs in Firebase Console?

Comment: @ManuelMB in firebase console I get the error mentioned in the question

Comment: Which plan are you using Spark or Blaze? To use nodemailer you need to use plan Blaze (Pay as you go)

Comment: @ManuelMB yes, I use the Blaze plan

Comment: Are you using a gmail email account?

Comment: @ManuelMB not, it's not gmail account, it's a custom email but the port/host are correct

Comment: My previous question was because Gmail may not allow access to non-Google apps citing security reasons.

You can change settings in Gmail's My Account->Sign-in & Security https://myaccount.google.com/security?utm_source=OGB&pli=1#connectedapps

Comment: Also for Gmail, Display Unlock Captcha

If you’re still getting an error on the functions log, you may want to unlock captcha by clicking here.

https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Consider try it using a Gmail account (Be aware of my previous comments)

Comment: @ManuelMB not sure if it's because of this. Because I have one more function that sends an email with the same `transporter` and it works, I've tested it 10 minutes ago

Comment: Should not be: const mailOptions = { to: email } instead of const mailOptions = { to: "mail" }?

Comment: I've changed the email address with some placeholder for this question, instead of mail in my code it's a real adress

Comment: ok, I just trying to help, but without success -:), I hope you manage to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by creating a new transporter and I've added it inside the function:

```
exports.sendMailUser =
  functions.firestore.document("collection/Users").onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const transporter2 = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: host,
      port: 465,
      debug: true,
      secure: true, 
      auth: {
        user: user,
        pass: pass,
      },
    });
    var data = snapshot.after.data();
    var dataReceived = data.users;
    var body = "As dori crearea unui cont pe portalul e-Radauti cu urmatoarele date: <br>" + dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].name + "<br>" + dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].email + "<br>" + "password:" + dataReceived[dataReceived.length - 1].password;
    var mailOptions = {
      from: "Adaugare User pe portal-ul e-Radauti",
      to: to,
      subject: "Adaugare user pe portalul e-Radauti",
      bcc: bcc,
      html: body,
    };
    //console.log(mailOptions);
    await transporter2.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return null;
  });
```